# after npm install and npm run dev console throws error, even though project works on another machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I installed a well working project on my home machine and after compiling fine it throws an error in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
at eval (index.umd.js?e3f3:5)
at eval (index.umd.js?e3f3:5)
at eval (index.umd.js?e3f3:5)
at eval (index.umd.js?e3f3:2)
at Object.eval (index.umd.js?e3f3:1)
at eval (index.umd.js:2523)
at Object../node_modules/vuetify-dialog/dist/index.umd.js (app.js:1611)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at eval (app.js?6d40:1)
at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:1667)
```

and here's some lines from app.js if that helps

```
19. /******/        // Execute the module function
20. /******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
21. /******/
```

The project works fine on another computer. I upgraded nodejs and npm. I'm out of ideas now. I'm using Vuetify.js

Comment: Did you try this: https://esausilva.com/2017/07/11/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-two-solutions/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, then I changed into yarn and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `node_modules` folder and package.lock.json, then run `npm i` again